# How to create custom datatype String in C Programming language?

Tags: c

I want to create a custom data type String. With that data type I want to use code like below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main(void)
{
    String name = "MD A Barik";
    printf("%s", name);
}
```

How may I implement String datatype in C programming languages!

Comment: typedef char *String; makes String a synonym for character pointer(char *).

Comment: `typedef const char *String;` would be sufficient in your example. (You didn't tell if you have more requirements than assigning a string literal and using `printf` with format `%s".)

Comment: You *can't*. You can create an *alias* (like the one shown by @LilyAB) but it's not always a good idea to hide details behind aliases, especially for pointers. The only way to add a proper type is to modify the compiler itself, but then it wouldn't really be a C compiler anymore (since the language it would compile doesn't follow the C specification).

Comment: `typedef const char *String;` Please don't.  CS50 generates enough confusion as it is with its obfuscation of fundamental types.

Answer (score 3):

A bunch of ways!

1. Study C for many years well enough to write your own elaborate set of functions and structures (but not classes), such that you create something more or less useful for you, but that nobody else will ever be able to use.
2. Switch to C++.
3. Wish upon a star.

Really, as comments above have noted, C ***does not support this*** and there's simply no way to pretend that it does.  Efforts such as my #1 above would be a huge amount of work, and entirely counterproductive.

It's a totally fair question to wish for, but you really need to take "no" for an answer here.

Answer (score -3):

```
typedef char* String;
```

or just use `char*` directly.

```
char* name = "MD A Barik";
```

You should be aware that this `String` behaves very differently than the `std::string` of c++. e.g. in c++ you can add two strings to concatenate, in C, you need to use `strcat`

Comment: IMO `typedef char* String` is a very bad idea. It makes believe that there is actually a `String` type when it's only a pointer.

Comment: It differs in other ways too. For example, `String s = "hello"; s[0]='H';` is illegal.

Comment: As the right answer is "*You cannot.*" this answer implicitly is wrong.

Comment: As long as the user is aware that this `String` type is NOT the same and in fact very different from the `std::string` of c++, I believe this answer is correct.